# NSString property loses value in IBAction method

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring, ibaction

I have a NSString property, self.textFromTextVC, in a Viewcontroller and it's value becomes null in the IBAction method.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"text before alarm is created: %@", self.textFromTextVC);

}
```

The methods below are in the same '.m' file and they keep the value of the NSString property.

```
-(void)setPropertyTextToReceivedText:(NSString *)text
{

    self.textFromTextVC = text;

    NSLog(@"text received from text VC: %@", self.textFromTextVC);

    [self doesStringKeepValue]; //I call this method to check and see if the NSString value     
                                //was retained

}

-(void)doesStringKeepValue
{

    NSLog(@"keep value: %@", self.textFromTextVC); //NSString value the same from the above
                                                   //method
}
```

Below is how I have declared the NSString property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textFromTextVC;
```

Basically, I'm setting the `self.textFromTextVC` before the IBAction method is called and that is why I'm confused.  I'm really not sure what is going on.  I have ARC selected.
I'm hoping that I'm just making a simple mistake...help?
Thanks,

Below is the method in another viewcontroller where I called setPropertyTextToReceivedText:

```
@implementation TextViewController

@synthesize typedText;


- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {

    [self.typedText resignFirstResponder];

    AlarmViewController *receiver = [[AlarmViewController alloc]init];
    [receiver setPropertyTextToReceivedText:self.typedText.text];

    //[self showAlert];
}
```

Comment: The value of `textFromTextVC` cannot become null in `buttonPressed:` because there is no code that could cause it. It already is null before that method is called. So please show the code where `textFromTextVC` is initially assigned any value.

Comment: where are you calling `setPropertyTextToReceivedText` show us the code

Comment: @Codo I assign self.textFromTextVC in the method setPropertyTexttoReceivedText.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore below is the method in another viewcontroller where I called setPropertyTextToReceivedText:

Comment: I'm able to see the NSString value in the AlarmViewController, just not in the IBAction method.

Comment: @adam where is your `ViewController` presented/pushed ??

Answer (score 2):

What your problem is `receiver` is different object than your `VC` which is shown (present/pushed).

```
AlarmViewController *receiver = [[AlarmViewController alloc]init];
[receiver setPropertyTextToReceivedText:self.typedText.text];
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the above code is incorrect because it is called in the textViewController, so the ViewController object needs to be of class alarmViewControler so that the method 'setPropertyTextToReceivedText' will work?  is that wrong?

Comment: @adam Just show the code where you have `pushed or presented` your `AlarmViewController` . My point was that your `pushed` `AlarmViewController` object is different from that you are creating in `doneButton` button event

Comment: @adam, If you are calling `setPropertyTextToReceivedText` on `receiver`, you need to present/push the same view controller. If you are creating another `AlarmViewController` and presenting that, you wont see this value set there.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`NSLog(@"text before alarm is created: %@", self.textFromTextVC);`

To this:

`NSLog(@"%@: text before alarm is created: %@", self, self.textFromTextVC);`

And it will probably show you that you are indeed looking at two different object instances of the same class.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot:

```
@synthesize textFromTextVC;
```

Comment: its not required at all... @synthesize was used in older days :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya really??? To my surprise! But I think the only reason for `self.textFromTextVC = text` isn't working cause `textFromTextVC` is not set at all..

Comment: In newer xcode, you only define `@property` and `@synthesize` is done automatically. and its not visible. however you can override it  by your own.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya you mean the latest one? It sounds cool, but the OP might still use the old versions. :p

Comment: No, he mentioned he is using ARC... So thing he is using 4.x

Comment: @AnoopVaidya what about `@synthesize typedText;` in this code snippet...? Well, it seems he is not on SO right now. He'll explain it. ;)

Comment: Even if you dont do in Xcode 4.4, `@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName` is there. If he is using prior to this... then might be, but he would get warning if no `@synthesize` is not there...isn't it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I use Xcode 4.6-DP3 right now, but without any warning when I comment out one of my `@synthesize`. And what's more, the animation on it didn't work.. (without ARC)

Comment: if you commented out, then it will take its default one as `_prop`.

Comment: Also I am feelin that you are fooling me, as you have 1.5x points than me.. :p

Comment: _"if you commented out, then it will take its default one as _prop"_ I know, so that's why I suggest the OP to add `@synthesize`. _"..., as you have 1.5x points than me"_, not a big deal, that's just a number. :p

Comment: But he is always using `self.property` this means it is synthsized, otherwise he had to use _proprty. :)

Comment: Aha, yes, but he got nil when use `self.property`. I think we don't need to discuss on this any more. It's endless.. I think the OP'll untie our doubts. ;)

Comment: Hey All! Thanks for the help.  I'm still stuck.  What I cannot get over is that I have a NSLog in the alarmViewController that confirms the self.textFromTextVC received the text value from the TextViewController.  However, when I push the button in the alarmViewController the value of self.textFromTextVC is null.  I've seen some people talking about 'file's owner' in IB, but I'm using Xcode 4.5 and I don't see a 'file Owner' option.  Is this correct? incorrect?

Comment: @adam have you tried to add `@synthesize textFromTextVC;` below `@implementation TextViewController`?